# show two different models as the foreign key

Tags: django

There's two models Groups and Sub_groups. How can I show both models in particulars field as foreign key?

models.py

```
class Groups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    under = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Sub_groups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    under = models.ForeignKey(Groups, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='sub_groups')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        
class Voucher(models.Model):
    particulars = models.ForeignKey(Groups, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='vouchers')
    #how to add both groups and sub_groups data in particulars here?
```

What I have done so far:

forms.py

```
class PaymentVoucherForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaymentVoucherForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Populate the choices for the 'particulars' field with both groups and subgroups
        group_choices = [("g_" + str(group.id), group.name) for group in Groups.objects.all()]
        subgroup_choices = [("sg_" + str(subgroup.id), subgroup.name) for subgroup in Sub_groups.objects.all()]
        
        # Concatenate the group and subgroup choices
        all_choices = group_choices + subgroup_choices
        
        # Set the choices for the 'particulars' field
        self.fields['particulars'].choices = all_choices
    class Meta:
        model = Voucher
        fields = ['particulars',]
```

template:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form|crispy}}
    <input class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It gives following error:
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.

P.S g_ and sg_ are added to the ids of groups and sub_groups respectively since both the models has same ids like 1,2 etc. Hence inorder to distinguish whether the choice is a group or sub_group, g_ and sg_ are added.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to use is Multi-table inheritance:

Define a Super-Class for Groups and Sub_groups (or maybe just make Sub_groups derived from Groups)

```
class SuperGroup (models.Model):
    # maybe you want to store your fields here, cause it seems both sub-classes have the same fields.

class Groups (SuperGroup):
    # your fields here

class Sub_Groups (SuperGroup):
    # your fields here
```

This will allow you to use SuperGroup as ForeignKey-class and access both Groups and Sub_Groups with this foreign-key.

Note, that to reference fields of the Group and Sub_group models, you can only do `voucher_instance.name` if you have defined the fields in SuperClass. Otherwise you have to adress the sub-classes explicitly: `voucher_instance.sub_group.name` or `voucher_instance.group.name`. Also the db-schema for these models are a bit different from what you might expect. For details see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

You than don't have to do any magic with the choices, the ModelForm will give you all choices correctly.